# hide modalpopup from IFrame

Tags: asp.net, ajax

net ajax app. I have one modelpopup that shows a IFrame and inside Iframe I show one asp.net page.
I want to hide the modelpopup  when user click on close button in page inside IFrame.
How can I find the opener modalpopup?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with simple javascript you can access the top window javascript values or functions by using the **window.top.document**, for example:

```
 window.top.FunctionToRun();
```

and find elements by

```
window.top.document.getElementById("ControlIdToFindOnParent")
```

or direct

```
window.top.document.forms[0].ControlNameOnParent
```

If you using jQuery you can use the

```
jQuery("#ControlIdToFindOnParent", window.top.document)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reload the page from javascript, this will close the popup, and reload the data on the page. If the main page was a listview and the popup edited one of the items in the list, the reload also updates the edited item.

```
window.top.location.href = window.top.location.href;
```

No need to target a function of the parent page.