# return value to parent page from modal pop up extender

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

```
<asp:Button ID="btnCheckPatientID" CssClass="cssbutton" runat="server" Text="Check"
                    OnClick="btnCheckPatientID_Click" />
                <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="btnCheckPatientID_ModalPopupExtender" runat="server"
                    PopupControlID="panelCheckPatient" TargetControlID="hiddenTargetControlForModalPopup"
                    BackgroundCssClass="modalbackground" CancelControlID="btnClose">
                </asp:ModalPopupExtender>

<asp:Button runat="server" ID="hiddenTargetControlForModalPopup" Style="display: none" />

<div id="panelCheckPatient" class="modalpopup" style="display: none">
        <iframe id="iframeCheckPatient" class="csstable" runat="server" width="550px" height="485px" scrolling="auto">
        </iframe>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" CssClass="cssbutton" Text="Close" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

**Serve Code**

```
protected void btnCheckPatientID_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        iframeCheckPatient.Attributes["src"] = "Check_Patient.aspx?patientID=" + txtPatientID.Text.Trim();
        btnCheckPatientID_ModalPopupExtender.Show();
    }
```

I have open an Ajax Modal popup on click of btnCheckPatientID.
In Modal Popup load an iframe which contains Check_Patient.aspx page.All working correctly.

In Check_Patient.aspx there is Pass button. 
On click of button i have to return some value to parent page.

What should i do.
Search on google but cant find any help

Comment: you can set session on child page and get back values to parent page.

Comment: Hi sain pradeep Agreed to store value in session..How to close Modal popup in iframe page(Check_Patient.aspx) on double click of tr in javascript

Comment: See on this link :-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876986/hide-modalpopup-from-iframe

Answer (score 0):

You can use button postbackurl property where you need to specify your parent page  address and on the parent page use the following code:

let say you have a textbox on your popup, you can use the same as folows

```
TextBox txtnew=(TextBox)PreviousPage.FindControl("id or name of control");
```

and then use its value OR create a property on popup page like

```
public string popupdata
{
   get; set;
}
popupdata=your poppage value;
```

now access the same on parent page using

```
string str=PreviousPage.popupData.Tostring();
```

OR you can use cookies or session as your other options.

Comment: thanks Geek How to close Modal popup in iframe page(Check_Patient.aspx) on double click of tr in javascript

Comment: on clientClick of your button, you can call your close method on client side(using javascript) to close your pop-up.